# Registring QList<CustomType>

Tags: qt

I got a runtime crash when registering a QList (CustomType is a Q_GADGET generate by the repc (Qt remote object compiler)).

Actually I am trying to expose a list of custom type using Qt Remote Object.

file.rep :

```
POD Service(QString name, QUrl enpoint)
POD Services(QList<Service> svcs)


class ROObject
{
    PROP(bool state = false);
    PROP(Services services);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QRemoteObjectHost>

#include "rotest.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qRegisterMetaType<QList<Service>>();

    ROTest t;

    QList<Service> l;
    l.push_back(Service("houssem", QUrl("local:houssem")));
    l.push_back(Service("houss", QUrl("local:houss")));

    Services ss(l);

    t.setServices(ss);

    QRemoteObjectHost host;
    host.setHostUrl(QUrl("local:s"));
    host.enableRemoting(&t);

    qDebug() << "Services : " << t.services().svcs().count();

    return a.exec();
}
```

error:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Qt doesn't know how to serialize your custom types.

In addition to registering it as a meta type, you need to [implement and register stream operators for it](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators):

```
void qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators(const char *typeName)
```

> Registers the stream operators for the type T called typeName.
>
> Afterward, the type can be streamed using QMetaType::load() and
>   QMetaType::save(). These functions are used when streaming a QVariant.

```
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<MyClass>("MyClass");    
// The stream operators should have the following signatures:    
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const MyClass &myObj);
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, MyClass &myObj);
```

Also, what you actually need to register as a meta type is `Service` and **not** `QList<Service>`. Once service is registered and its streaming operators are implemented you should be all set, Qt knows how to handle the `QList` part.

Comment: I did what you suggested but I got another error : http://imgur.com/a/azuZO

Comment: Hmmm, so maybe you need to register the list too? Also, did you `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()`? I don't see it in the code. `qRegisterMetaType()` requires also a `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()`

Comment: no I didn't, do I need to put in the file generated by repc or I can put it anywhere ?

Comment: Put it after the type declaration.

Comment: I did it after the Service type definition and after the Services type definition, but still the same error.
Here the repc generated file. https://pastebin.com/Q6kKmY20

Comment: @Houss_gc - try a generic streaming operator implementation instead of `copyStoredProperties()`. You have only two members, input and output them by hand. Your usage of that function is incorrect, it takes 3 parameters, the object's **metaobject**, and then object and stream or stream and object depending on whether you copy to or from.

Comment: I didn't write that code it's generated automatically by the remote object compiler of Qt. I will make the changes as suggested.

Comment: according to this article https://woboq.com/blog/qmetatype-knows-your-types.html types declared with Q_GADGET are automatically declared with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, we need just to use qRegisterMetaType<T>() to be able to use them in Queued connections.

Comment: Yes I suspected that might be the case, since a gadget will have meta data generated. Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: not yet still the same error of unable to read data, I am trying to change the rep file and make the class property like PROP(QList<Service>) instead.

Comment: with the new change made, now I have a replica in the default state, no data transfer between the source and the replica is made. I put a topic in the qt forum https://forum.qt.io/topic/81160/qtro-exposing-qlist-customtype-as-a-property

Comment: I don't have any experience with the remote object, maybe someone else will help out.

Comment: I managed to make it work, by exposing the QList<Service> to the class in the rep file, And to wait the Replica object to be in a valid state by handling the stateChanged event of the QRemoteObjectReplica to get finally access to the list.